# perl XML::Feed error reading html content inside rss feed

Tags: html, xml, perl, rss

i´m trying to parse and read the content of a rss feed and getting an error.

this is my rss feed file (for test porpose)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:Test="http://www.Test.com">
<channel>
    <title>Deportes - Test.com</title>
       <link>http://www.Test.com</link>
           <description>Últimas noticias de deportes</description>
           <item>
                    <title><![CDATA[El 'Chacho' Coudet es el nuevo entrenador de Rosario Central]]></title>
                    <link>http://442.Test.com/2014-12-15-326653-coudet-fue-presentado-como-nuevo-dt-de-central/</link>
                    <description><![CDATA[El&nbsp;Chacho, Tengo mucha alegr&iacute;a y ganas de empezar a trabajar.&nbsp;No esperaba que sea ac&aacute;&rdquo;, reconoci&oacute;.]]></description>
                    <category><![CDATA[Deportes]]></category>
                    <pubDate>15 12 2014 06:15:0 +0000</pubDate>
                    <enclosure url="http://www.Test.com/__export/1418678333348/sites/diarioTest/img/2014/12/15/deportes/1215_coudet_g_fb.jpg" type="image/jpeg"><![CDATA[El Chacho Coudet]]></enclosure>
                    <author><![CDATA[]]></author>
                    <content><![CDATA[<p>Eduardo Coudet&nbsp;fue presentado como nuevo entrenador     deRosario Central&nbsp.</p>
]]></content>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

this is my test.pl script file.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Feed;

my $feed = XML::Feed->parse("test.xml");

for my $entry ($feed->entries) {

   print $entry->content;

}
```

when i run this code i get this error.

```
Can't use string ("<p>Eduardo Coudet&nbsp;fue prese"...) as a HASH ref while "st
rict refs" in use at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/XML/Feed/Entry/Format/RSS.pm li
ne 91.
```

i think is a bug inside XML::Feed

Reference: https://github.com/davorg/xml-feed/blob/master/lib/XML/Feed/Format/RSS.pm

Thanks

Comment: You may be right. What do you think StackOverflow should do about it? Can I suggest using a different XML parser instead? I would suggest `XML::Twig`, but that doesn't like the unicode character.

Comment: Just that, give me some ideas, thank you for your comment.  :)

Comment: I would suggest you file a bug report on CPAN, and then find another module you like to do the same job.

Comment: Thanks Sobreque, i created a bug report on CPAN
https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=100976

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED

The developer of this library fixed the bug on version 0.53

https://github.com/davorg/xml-feed/issues/16

Thanks, i hope this help other with the same issue